# Whats so interesting about the picket fence at the St. Johns Dairy in Episode 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

When you are in the front garden of the St. Johns Dairy farm in Episode 2 you can examine part of the picket fence to the left (as you are facing it) of the gate leading up to the front door of the house. Lee remarks that it is, 'very interesting' or words to that effect.

Yet it seems entirely unremarkable to me and I have now finished this chapter and the only thing that seemed to relate was,

> After I was confronted by Andrew St. John outside the house and was fighting him we
>  fell down the banking and crashed through roughly the same part of the fence but there >! is no way that Lee could have known that was going to happen.

Did I miss something about this fence?

Comment: Since something happens with the fence later, it's probably a bug that you can interact with it earlier in the story. The "very interesting" response might just be some sort of default interaction reaction, that's less immersion breaking than the adventure game standard of "I can't do anything with that right now".

Comment: It could be just that he thought it was well built. Lee is a but odd...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Tacroy said in the comments, this is a common default interaction reaction for when an item doesn't have a use, it's an alternative to just saying "*Nothing to do with this item*" so your immersion isn't broken. I think Lee sometimes also says things like "*Nope*" and "*Hmm...*"

EDIT: Found a video of this scene, seems like it's just an observation, at MOST I'd say it's foreshadowing to what you said in OP: ( [Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=csGNaUH-3Vs#t=830s) )

Comment: Found a video of this scene, seems like it's just an observation, at MOST I'd say it's foreshadowing to what you said in OP [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=csGNaUH-3Vs#t=830s)

Comment: since Lee says a different line in the video, if you add that to your answer and no else comes up with anything by the end of the bounty I will award it to you.